# How to manage API permissions? javascript

Tags: javascript, google-api

I've written some client-side app and tried to test it. How it turned out only I can use it. Anyone else will get such error.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Forbidden"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Forbidden"
 }
}
```

What does it mean? How to solve this?
There is my code. There i'm getting Email, name, surname and user photo. I want to get the number of youtube channel subscribers and work with youtube later. For example I want to rate some videos directly from the site.

```
function resultFindUserByEmail()
{
  if (ajaxRet['isUserFinded'])
  {
    cf_JSON.clear();
    cf_JSON.addItem(    'email',email     );
    var jsonstr = cf_JSON.make();
    ajax_post('doyoutubelogin','loginres','index.php',jsonstr,c_dologin);
  }else{

    gapi.client.init({
      discoveryDocs: ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/people/v1/rest"],
      clientId: OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
      scope: OAUTH2_SCOPES
    }).then(function () {       
      var request = gapi.client.people.people.get({
      'resourceName': 'people/me'
    }).then(function(response) {

        var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response.body).names;
        surname = parsedResponse[0].familyName;
        name = parsedResponse[0].givenName;

        photo = JSON.parse(response.body).photos[0].url; 
        addYoutubeUser();       
      });                  
    });
  }
}
function addYoutubeUser() {
    cf_JSON.clear();
    cf_JSON.addItem(        'Email',email              );
    cf_JSON.addItem(    'Firstname',name               );
    cf_JSON.addItem(     'Lastname',surname            );
    cf_JSON.addItem(        'Image',photo              );
    var jsonstr = cf_JSON.make();
    ajax_post('addyoutubeuser','loginres','index.php',jsonstr,c_dologin);
}

var API_KEY = '<Key removed for posting>'; 
var API_KEY1='<Key removed for posting>';
var OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '<Key removed for posting>';
var OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID1 = '<Key removed for posting>';
var OAUTH2_SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl';
var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest"];

  var GoogleAuth;
  function handleClientLoad() {
    // Load the API's client and auth2 modules.
    // Call the initClient function after the modules load.
    gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
  }

  function initClient() {
    // Retrieve the discovery document for version 3 of YouTube Data API.
    // In practice, your app can retrieve one or more discovery documents.
    var discoveryUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest';

    // Initialize the gapi.client object, which app uses to make API requests.
    // Get API key and client ID from API Console.
    // 'scope' field specifies space-delimited list of access scopes.  
    gapi.client.init({
        'apiKey': API_KEY,
        'discoveryDocs': [discoveryUrl,"https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest"],
        'clientId': OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': OAUTH2_SCOPES
    }).then(function () {      
      GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
      //GoogleAuth.grant(OAUTH2_SCOPES);

      // Listen for sign-in state changes.
      GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

      // Handle initial sign-in state. (Determine if user is already signed in.)
      var user = GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();
      setSigninStatus();

      // Call handleAuthClick function when user clicks on
      //      "Sign In/Authorize" button.
      $('#sign-in-or-out-button').click(function() {
        handleAuthClick();
      }); 
      $('#revoke-access-button').click(function() {
        revokeAccess();      
      }); 
    });
  }

  function handleAuthClick() {
    if (GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get()) {
      // User is authorized and has clicked 'Sign out' button.
      GoogleAuth.signOut();
    } else {
      // User is not signed in. Start Google auth flow.
      GoogleAuth.signIn();
    }
  }

  function revokeAccess() {
    GoogleAuth.disconnect();
  }

  function setSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
    var user = GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();

    var isAuthorized = user.hasGrantedScopes(OAUTH2_SCOPES);
    if (isAuthorized) {
      $('#sign-in-or-out-button').html('Sign out');
      $('#revoke-access-button').css('display', 'inline-block');
      $('#auth-status').html('You are currently signed in and have granted ' +
          'access to this app.');

          //// get gmail Email
      gapi.client.init({
        'apiKey': API_KEY,
        'discoveryDocs': ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest"],
        'clientId': OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
        'scope': OAUTH2_SCOPES
      }).then(function () {    
        var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.getProfile({
        'userId': 'me'
      }).then(function(response) {

          email = JSON.parse(response.body).emailAddress;

          cf_JSON.clear();
          cf_JSON.addItem(    'email',email     );
          var jsonstr = cf_JSON.make();
          tryFindUserByEmail(jsonstr);                  
        });                  
      });

      // try to find email


    } else {
      $('#sign-in-or-out-button').html('Вход через Youtube');
      $('#revoke-access-button').css('display', 'none');
      $('#auth-status').html('You have not authorized this app or you are ' +
          'signed out.');
    }
  }

  function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
    setSigninStatus();
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to stack this is a very good question but in order for us to help you we need to see your code and understand what it is you are trying to do.  Just posting the error is not normally a good way to solve the problem there are to many things that can be causing it.   Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Now please edit your question and tell us what it is you are tyring to do.  You are connecting to Youtube API, gmail API, people API and doing something with the discovery services.

Comment: @DaImTo There i'm getting Email, name, surname and user photo. I want to get the number of youtube channel subscribers and work with youtube later. For example I want to rate some videos directly from the site.

Comment: Ok who's videos / channel?  The users videos or just random videos / channels?

Comment: @DaImTo random youtube videos. But it's not important right now. Now  there an issue with authorization. By the way I don't know how to manage this scopes. May i ask you to help me and provide some information about scopes managing?

Comment: Do this one step at a time check this.  Get it to work and come back we can talk about YouTube and adding another scope https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/js  I havent done JavaScript development in years I can read it and point you in the right direction but your going to have to code it yourself

Answer (score 0):

How to manage permissions:

When you authenticate a user you are given access to that users account data and only that user.   So if you are trying to access data on someone else's account they are not going to have permissions to access it and you are going to get the 403 forbidden error.

Without seeing your code its hard to know what you are doing, but I can guess.

1. You are using Oauth2 to authenticate users.
2. You are trying to access something with a hard coded id belonging to your personal account which the user does not have access.

How to fix it will depend on what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: Now just tell me what it is you are trying to do you seam to be mixing a lot of scopes.

Comment: Does it mean that i can not use OAuth2?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check some authentication in the API url like 
username , ipaddress , token etc.
Based on the parameter you can control the permission on your API request.for example

```
http://some/thing?username="testuser"&ipaddress="323.2323.232.32"
```

You can find the parameters value using the function below

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
  if (!url) url = window.location.href;
  name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
  var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
  if (!results) return null;
  if (!results[2]) return '';
  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

And then make you check and implement your error and redirection for specific users.

I guess it will help full for you , Thanks !

Comment: I'll try it. Thank you too for your answer!